# Get item price excluding tax in email invoice - Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, price, tax, vat

We want to load the product price excluding tax inside the invoice email.
Therefore we copied the default file to: /app/design/frontend/theme/theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/invoice/default.phtml

Our tax setting for "Catalog Prices" is set to "Including Tax".

And we tried a lot, but at the moment the price is display including tax with:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency($_item->getPrice(), true, false);?>
```

How can we get the price excluding tax?

Answer (score 0):

In \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface

You have getTaxAmount()

What if you instead try:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency($_item->getPrice()-$_item->getTaxAmount(), true, false);?>
```

Comment: Thanks Kristoffer, but that does not work. We get a total wrong value in that case.

Comment: If you use only getTaxAmount, do u get the correct tax amount?

Comment: It can be that you have to divide getTaxAmount with the quantity in cart before you substract

Comment: Thanks! Will try that.